# App showing mono (single camera) view ONLY on iPhone 6 plus running iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm currently struggling with an app I developed using Unity 3D and the google cardboard package. My app currently runs with no problems whatsoever on several Android and iOS devices but when running on an iPhone 6 plus with iOS 9 it will only show the left eye view of the scene. The middle bar is visible, the gear config icon is visible and the left eye is perfectly visible. The right eye just looks black (nada). Only on iPhone 6 plus with iOS 9.

Any ideas anyone? halp?

Answer (score 0):

So, what I finally did was reset the CardboardMain prefab and everything worked again. I tried several other things including tampering with Google's code but the only thing that worked was this. I never knew what was the error but this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this recently and it seems as tho there is a bug with the SDK. This occurs if you check the 'Direct Render' checkbox on the StereoController.